# "Whenever you arrive/are arrived/were arrived"

Tags: present-tense, present-perfect

Which one of these sentences is grammatically correct? Would it be alright if the other sentences were being used in daily conversations?

> Let me know whenever **you arrive**.
>
> Let me know whenever **you're arrived**.
>
> Let me know whenever **you were arrived**.

Comment: Someone please edit the title of the question to something more appropriate. I couldn't come up with anything better that this!

Comment: ...you're arrived is like saying, ...you are walked...(?) and is wrong.  It should be ...whenever you arrive...or, whenever you have arrived..., as already answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best is a variation of the first:

> Let me know when you arrive.

The second two examples are incorrect, as *to be* isn't used followed by a past participle in this way.

An alternate formulation (which means pretty much the exact same thing) is to use the present perfect:

> Let me know when you've arrived.

The difference in meaning between the simple present (in my first example) and the present perfect (in my second example) is very small in this case.

Comment: Helpful, but you're assuming OP actually meant *when you arrive* not *whenever you arrive*.  Probably correctly, but a short explanation would be good.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is the only correct one. In both the second and third, you are using the improper form of "to be" for "you".

The proper forms of *arrive* in the second-person singular (2s) are:

- you arrive
- you do arrive
- you arrived
- you have arrived
- you will arrive
- you could arrive
- you would arrive
- you should arrive
- you shall arrive

*(Did I miss any conjugations?)*

Both "you are arrived" and "you're arrived" can be attributed to plural forms of "to be", but in English the plurals are usually reserved for only first- and third-person forms—*we* and *they*—however in some contexts "you" can be used for the 2P (second person plural—*y'all* colloquially) form. However, neither are regularly used in American English.

Comment: The question, and the grammaticality of the examples, are nothing whatever to do with singular vs. plural. They are about whether the _be arrived_ (in whatever tense, number or person) is grammatical in Modern English.